# Android Studio- What does it install by default?

Tags: java, android-studio, installation

So I'm a beginner. I was installing Android Studio but the installation was taking too long. I could see on the progress details, it said it had completed downloading some stuff.

It was taking too long, so I cancelled the installation and decided I was going to do it at night time. But when I clicked on the Android Studio icon, it just opened the IDE, it seemed to have skipped the downloading process that I had cancelled before.

So I went to SDK tools on the IDE and I'm not sure what stuff it downloads..
Is there a way, I can uninstall everything and install it again so it downloads everything by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view the installer tries to install needed dependencies for android development. If you cancel the download you can open android studio and use the android sdk manager to download needed android sdk.
For example for the AVD (Device Emulartor) you can add needed Plugin to Andorid Studio.
All other things should be done from the IDE and inform you about updates and new features.

Make sure all needed plugins for android development are installed.
[image: Android Plugins]